# regex whats wrong?

Tags: php, regex

What I did wrong? It still returns `21-11-2016`.

```
$string = '21-11-2016';
$pattern = '/({0-9}(2))-({0-9}(2))-({0-9}(4))/';
$rep = "Month: $2 , Day: $1 , Year: $3";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $rep, $string); 
die();
```

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) :)

Comment: I personally would have `$string = '21-11-2016'; $e = explode('-', $string); echo implode(' , ', array('Month: '.$e[1], 'Day: '.$e[0], 'Year: '.$e[2]));` and called it a day. Also, with a million iterations I got `.2` seconds vs `.4` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `{..}` and `(..)` at wrong place. Use:

```
echo preg_replace('/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/', $rep, $string);
```

`{...}` makes it a range and `[...]` makes it a character class.

Comment: oh....damn) Time to go to sleep... TY

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pattern you want:

```
$pattern = '/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/';
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/LYhvB

However, parsing dates with regex is not a good practice. Use built-in date functions!

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not a valid regex. You've got `[]` and `{}` reversed.

`[]` defines character classes and ranges, e.g. `[0-9]` is "all digits".
`{}` defines quantities. e.g. `{2}` means "two of the previous".
`()` defines a capture group. `(2)` is rather pointless. - you're just capturing a fixed `2`.

Since yours are backwards, you've got syntax errors from using invalid `{}` ranges, and wouldn't match anything anyways.

Try

```
/([0-9]{2}-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets and braces are messed up. It should be like this.

`([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uY2wX3/2)